# Python winrm node definition

Tags: rundeck, winrm

Actually I'm using rundeck WinRM overthere plugin to get Windows connection and command excutions, using this node definition template

```
<node name="XXXXXX" 
hostname="1.1.1.1" 
osFamily="Windows" 
osName="Microsoft Windows Server 2016" 
osArch="amd64"
node-executor="overthere-winrm"
file-copier="overthere-winrm"
winrm-cert-trust="all"
winrm-auth-type="ntlm"
winrm-protocol="https"
winrm-cmd="PowerShell"
winrm-password-storage-path="keys/project/TEST/XXXXX.password">
```

Note the above lines with

```
node-executor="overthere-winrm"
file-copier="overthere-winrm"
```

I'm trying to setup py-winrm plugin on a similar way like winrm-overthere plugin. I don't know if it's possible to setup pywinrm node and file executor on node definition when using pywinrm plugin.

Question

Can I setup pywinrm plugin with node-executor and file-copier attribute on node definition?

This setup enable me to use SSH globally on a project and pywinrm on Windows nodes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sure, is defined as a property like the old Overthere WinRM plugin, look at the [rundeck documentation](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/configuring.html#node-execution).

In the Pywinrm plugin case:

```
node-executor="WinRMPython"
file-copier="WinRMcpPython"
```